How to Debug Java Service Stopped Writing Logs Using Log4j2
The service itself is running fine. I have the same application running at 2 places both have same logging config. There are no warning or error messages about logging it just stops.
What could cause a Java service using Log4j2 to stop writing logs abruptly?
Are there any additional debugging steps I should take to identify and resolve this issue?
I tried collecting strace when the logging stops but it did not clarify the issue.

It could be the log file tmp location that been lost or the configuration of the xml log file

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
